# get the Image from ImageView and save it to SD card

Tags: android

I load images from the Adapter using Glide

```
Glide
  .with(holder.messagePhoto.getContext())
  .load(currentMessage.getMessageText())
  .into(holder.messagePhoto);
```

I want to save the image from the imageView `holder.messagePhoto` to SD card
I tried this:

```
 String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 File myDir = new File(root + "/req_images");

 myDir.mkdirs();
 Random generator = new Random();
 int n = 10000;
 n = generator.nextInt(n);
 String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
 File file = new File(myDir, fname);

 Log.i("saveIMG", "" + file);
 if (file.exists())
   file.delete();

 try {
   FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
   Bitmap  bm = ((BitmapDrawable) 
   holder.messagePhoto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
   bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, out);

   out.flush();
   out.close();

 } catch (Exception e) {
     Log.i("saveIMGerror", e.getMessage() );
 }
```

but it shows the error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: `but it shows the error:`. Well you have an exception. But you omitted that. Please start with it.

Comment: First you should solve `NullPointerException`. Then get `Uri` for SD card and save your image using Uri with `DocumentFile` or `DocumentContract` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load();
```

use glide like this